# Google chart from PHP variables

Tags: php, google-visualization

Im trying to figure out how to integrate a google chart with data I am calculating. Google only gives instructions for static data tables in their basic example and I don't know enough to interpret the rest of their instructions. Could someone pls give me some pointers as I have tried several methods and failing dismally.

This is a simple calculator for kids. You put in your savings and it tells you how much you will have and shows it in a table by year. I would like to chart year and balance for them as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Balance');

  for(var $ = 0; i <= $period ; i++) {
  data.addRow([$year[i], $new_balance[i]])
    }

    ]);
```

The results come from simple calculations. . .

```
   <?php for($i=0;$i<$_POST['period'];$i++):       
      $year=$current_year+$i;

     // contributions
     $total_contribution+=$_POST['contribution'];

   // interest
   $interest=$new_balance*($_POST['rate']/100);
   $total_interest+=$interest;

   //balances
   $new_balance=$new_balance+$interest+$_POST['contribution'];;
   $old_balance=$new_balance-$interest-$_POST['contribution'];;
```

$period is the number of years.

The calculator works and the table it builds is a function of the number of years (i.e. 1 row per year, but could someone help me getting this into google chart?

Thanks in advance

D

Answer (score 0):

You could do, but are not limited to, something like this:

```
data.addRows([
<?php
    echo "['" . $year . "'," . $balance . "],";
?>
]);
```

Let PHP create the rows for you.

(Take in mind that this is just an example and you'll have to optimize the script in order for it to work with your code)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Keon. It partially works in that it now generates a chart which has one piece of data in it (the final balance), but doesn't seem to capture all the data of the iterations to reach that balance. I have the google-chart script nested between the computation and a table that propagates each row as the computations run. Could you give me any insight by what you mean "optimise the script" and what I should be looking to do? Cheers D

Comment: You'll have to put your loop around it so it adds multiple rows, instead of just one like now.

Comment: Getting better thanks. Now it adds multiple rows, but they are all the final amount/year rather than each incremental balances of each step. I added the following statement around the data.addRows function - "for(var x = 0; x <= <?php echo @$_POST['period']?> ; x++) { "

Comment: Aah thats where you went wrong, i ment a forloop in PHP, which echo's for every period you add :) so something like: for($i=0;$i<$_POST['perdiod'];$i++){ echo "['" . $year . "'," . $balance . "],"; }

Comment: still not having any luck. tried the forloop and still giving me the 1st year and final balance for each data set. have run a counter to check its looping fine. I am using <?php echo number_format($balance)?> in a table below that correctly inserts the sequential data. Any other ideas?